# Trouble installing PHP5 modules

Tags: apache2, php

I followed this speed tutorial: https://www.liberiangeek.net/2015/11/how-to-easily-install-wordpress-on-ubuntu-15-10/ but I got stuck at Step 4...

When I run following code in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install php5 libapache2-mod-php5 php5-mysql php5-curl php5-gd php5-intl php-pear php5-imagick php5-imap php5-mcrypt php5-memcache php5-ming php5-ps php5-pspell php5-recode php5-sqlite php5-tidy php5-xmlrpc php5-xsl
```

I get following error messages from all packages:

Package "name_of_package" is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'name_of_package' has no installation candidate

...
..
.
What should I do? What source should I use and how do I add them?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP and Apache2 broken after upgrade to Ubuntu 16.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/761705/php-and-apache2-broken-after-upgrade-to-ubuntu-16-04)

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 16.04 removed php5 packages and removed those with PHP 7.0 packages that doesn't have php5, but just php inside package names, so replace your command with:

```
sudo apt-get install php libapache2-mod-php php-mysql php-curl php-gd php-intl php-pear php-imagick php-imap php-mcrypt php-memcache php-ming php-ps php-pspell php-recode php-sqlite php-tidy php-xmlrpc php-xsl
```

Similar question here: [PHP and Apache2 broken after upgrade to Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/761705/php-and-apache2-broken-after-upgrade-to-ubuntu-16-04) or [PHP rendered as text after Ubuntu 16.04 upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760787/php-rendered-as-text-after-ubuntu-16-04-upgrade)