# Phppgadmin does not work on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: phppgadmin

When I ran localhost/phppgadmin I've got the following message:

```
printHeader('', null, true); $rtl = (strcasecmp($lang['applangdir'], 'rtl') == 0); $cols = $rtl ? '*,'.$conf['left_width'] : $conf['left_width'].',*'; $mainframe = '' ?> printFooter(false); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to active the following module

```
sudo a2enmod php7.0
```

and install

```
sudo apt install php libapache2-mod-php
```

additionally read this thread: 
[Upgrade to 16.04. php7 not working in browser](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760907/upgrade-to-16-04-php7-not-working-in-browser/)